# What are the difference of "so…that" and " such…that"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Are these two the same? Or what's different? I often confuse them.
I know that "Such that" is a description of HOW something is to be done,but I don't know what is "so that mean".I need your help. Thank you！
Benjoin

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so-that-or-in-order-that

Comment: They are not at all the same but why are you Asking that here rather than, for instance, in English Language Learners?